# How to optimize the inference script to get a faster prediction of the classifier?

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, classification, pytorch

I have written the following prediction code that predicts from a trained classifier model. Now the prediction time is around 40s which I want to reduce as much as possible.

Can I do any optimization to my inference script or should I look for developments in training script?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision.models import resnet18
from torchvision.transforms import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.functional as F
from PIL import Image
import os
import sys
import argparse
import time 
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'To Predict from a trained model')

parser.add_argument('-i','--image', dest = 'image_name', required = True, help='Path to the image file')
args = parser.parse_args()

def predict_image(image_path):
    print("prediciton in progress")
    image = Image.open(image_path)

    transformation = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])

    image_tensor = transformation(image).float()
    image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)

    if cuda:
        image_tensor.cuda()

    input = Variable(image_tensor)
    output = model(input)

    index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
    return index

def parameters():
    hyp_param = open('param_predict.txt','r')
    param = {}
    for line in hyp_param:
        l = line.strip('\n').split(':')

def class_mapping(index):
    with open("class_mapping.json") as cm:
        data = json.load(cm)
    if index == -1:
        return len(data)
    else:
        return data[str(index)]

def segregate():
    with open("class_mapping.json") as cm:
        data = json.load(cm)
    try:
        os.mkdir(seg_dir)
        print("Directory " , seg_dir ,  " Created ") 
    except OSError:
        print("Directory " , seg_dir ,  " already created")
    for x in range (0,len(data)):
        dir_path="./"+seg_dir+"/"+data[str(x)]
        try:
            os.mkdir(dir_path)
            print("Directory " , dir_path ,  " Created ") 
        except OSError:
            print("Directory " , dir_path ,  " already created")


path_to_model = "./models/"+'trained.model'
checkpoint = torch.load(path_to_model)
seg_dir="segregation_folder"

cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()

num_class = class_mapping(index=-1)
print num_class
model = resnet18(num_classes = num_class)

if cuda:
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)
else:
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint, map_location = 'cpu')

model.eval()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    imagepath = "./Predict_Image/"+args.image_name
    since = time.time()
    img = Image.open(imagepath)
    prediction = predict_image(imagepath)
    name = class_mapping(prediction)
    print("Time taken = ",time.time()-since)

    print("Predicted Class: ",name)
```

The entire project can be found at 
https://github.com/amrit-das/custom_image_classifier_pytorch/

Comment: what part of your script takes the most time? have you tried to profile it?

Comment: predict_image() takes around 70% of the total execution time

Answer (score 4):

Without output from your profiler it's difficult to tell how much of that is because of inefficiencies in your code. That being said, PyTorch has a lot of startup overhead - in other words it's slow to initialize the library, model, load weights and to transfer it to GPU, as compared to inference time on a single image. This makes is pretty poor as a CLI utility for single-image prediction.

If your use-case really requires working with single images instead of batch-processing, there is not that much potential for optimization. Two options I see are

1. It *may* be worth it to skip GPU execution altogether and save on GPU allocations and transfers.
2. You will get better performance writing this code in C++ using [LibTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html). This is a plenty of development work though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also optimize inference itself by using e.g. [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU. It optimizes the inference performance by e.g. graph pruning or fusing some operations together while preserving accuracy.

You can find a full tutorial on how to convert the PyTorch model [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/102-pytorch-onnx-to-openvino).
Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[pytorch,onnx]
```

**Save your model to ONNX**

OpenVINO cannot convert PyTorch model directly for now but it can do it with ONNX model. This sample code assumes the model is for computer vision.

```
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "model.onnx", opset_version=11)
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert ONNX model**

The Model Optimizer is a command line tool which comes from OpenVINO Development Package so be sure you have installed it. It converts the ONNX model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. It also changes the precision to FP16 for better performance (you can use FP32 as well). Run in command line:

```
mo --input_model "model.onnx" --input_shape "[1,3, 224, 224]" --mean_values="[123.675, 116.28 , 103.53]" --scale_values="[58.395, 57.12 , 57.375]" --data_type FP16 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference on the CPU**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, just use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.